# Why can I access private/protected methods using Object#send in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, language-design, access-specifier

### The class

```
class A

  private
  def foo
    puts :foo
  end

  public
  def bar
    puts :bar
  end

  private
  def zim
    puts :zim
  end

  protected
  def dib
    puts :dib
  end
end
```

### instance of A

```
a = A.new
```

### test

```
a.foo rescue puts :fail
a.bar rescue puts :fail
a.zim rescue puts :fail
a.dib rescue puts :fail
a.gaz rescue puts :fail
```

#### test output

```
fail
bar
fail
fail
fail
```

### .send test

```
[:foo, :bar, :zim, :dib, :gaz].each { |m| a.send(m) rescue puts :fail }
```

#### .send output

```
foo
bar
zim
dib
fail
```

### The question

The section labeled "Test Output" is the expected result. So why can I access private/protected method by simply `Object#send`?

### Perhaps more important:

What is the difference between `public`/`private`/`protected` in Ruby? When to use each? Can someone provide real world examples for `private` and `protected` usage?

Comment: Because ruby gives you rope :)

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896606/dont-the-ruby-methods-instance-eval-and-send-negate-the-benefits-of-private

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically: Because `send` doesn't do anything to check method visibility. (It would be more work to do so.)

Philosophically: Ruby is a very permissive language. You can already just open up a class and make any method you want public. The language designers implemented `send` in a way that allows it to override the restrictions normally imposed by `private`. Ruby 1.9 was originally going to have two variants, a `private`-respecting `send` and an unsafe variant called `send!`, but this was apparently dropped for backwards compatibility.

As for what `private`, `protected` and `public` mean:

- `public` methods can be called by any sender
- `protected` methods cannot be called outside of an instance of the method's class or an instance of a subclass
- `private` methods cannot be called with an explicit receiver (with a couple of exceptions, such as setter methods, which always have to have an explicit receiver, and so can be called within the class that way)

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. Could you add some real-world examples for *appropriate* use of `protected` and `private`? :)

Comment: Good answer. It may be worth pointing out that Ruby 1.9 introduces `Kernel#public_send` which will not call protected/private methods. It's available for Ruby 1.8 with the `backports` gem.

Comment: @smotchkkiss, that sounds like a separate question altogether.